# Why i can't use bootstrap and font link in same html file?

Tags: html, css, frontend

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet">
```

I am using these two links but not applying to my file.

Comment: Please post a more complete sample file. You also need to make sure these are in the HEAD of the HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you be more specific, what is not working? have you tried changing font-family of the element you want to change font of? Here is font applied to the body.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/wotusas/

Answer (score 0):

You can use them both at the same time, that should not be a problem.

To make the font getting applied to your site, you also need some CSS rules. these also need to have higher precedence than the ones from the boostrap file, or the same precedence but applied after the bootstrap file.